# Combine CSS of a wordpress website

Tags: css, wordpress, pagespeed

When I run the pagespeed test of Google with my website, it tells me to optimize the CSS delivery.

I checked a lot of websites, tried to combine my CSS files into one and deregistered the `wp_enqueue_styles` handles. My new CSS file loaded when I tested, but the website was void of CSS . (I deregistered files like Bootstrap and FontAwesome).

It seems that it did not load the CSS of my new file, although I copied and pasted exactly what was in the old CSS files.

For information,  I am using the [Beaver Builder Child Theme](http://kb.wpbeaverbuilder.com/article/31-install-the-beaver-builder-theme-and-child-theme) and plugin. I created a folder `includes/css` in the root directory of my website in which I placed the new CSS file. This new file I loaded in `header.php`.

I [followed exactly the steps described here](https://speedrak.com/how-to-combine-css-stylesheets-wordpress/).

Could someone help me with the steps to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you link the CSS file you created in the page in question?
Something like this in your head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/mynewcss.css" />
```

Also, if you have a test page set up, I can tell you exactly what you need to do.

Comment: yes I did, it appears in the head of the page when I load it, maybe there is something wrong in my CSS. The website is: https://www.xt2-extenders.com/. Now I removed the deregister functions, because it breaks the website and it is already live. But you can see the new CSS file here: https://www.xt2-extenders.com/includes/css/custom_plugins.20171130.css

Comment: Another thing you may want to look into is that you are putting the css files in the right order. if you want your css to show up instead of certain bootstrap css, it must come after the bootstrap in the css file.

Comment: Ok, so I tried what you suggested. I put bootstrap CSS at the top, it didn't work. I also tried to put all the CSS into the CSS file of my child theme. My custom CSS is loaded, but it seems that when I run the page no CSS at all is actually loaded. Here is a link of some screenshots I made so you can have an idea: https://imgur.com/a/qeR7Z. You'll also see my website when no CSS is loaded. I really tried everything, is there a problem in the CSS syntax?